# Use foreach to add multiple elements to list<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, foreach

As for a school assignment I have to add multiple textbox.texts to my list(`List<string> snackList = new List<string>();`). Each time the user clicks the save button and choses for MessageBoxResult.yes it will add an element to the list. The problem is that when the user presses no, it will display the list in a listbox but will only show the last submitted text.

So far I have the assumption that I have to use a foreach loop, but I could be wrong. I've been trying to search for a solution online, but sadly nothing has helped me.

My code

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBoxResult bevestig = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to order another snack?","Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
           List<string> snackList = new List<string>();
           snackList.Add(tbOrder.Text);

           if (bevestig == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
           {
             tbOrder.Text = "";
             tbOrder.Focusable = true;
             tbOrder.Focus();
            }
           else
           {
             lbOrderlist.ItemsSource = snackList;    
           }  
        }
```

Comment: Tip: any time you make a variable (like `snackList`) _inside_ a method, it will be wiped out as soon as the method is done, so the next time the method is called, it will start fresh.

Comment: you need to scope your variable at the class level rather than inside the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>There is good reason to close this question as 'typo', which is why this post is Community Wiki.</sub>

---

Your list variable is declared *within* the scope of your method. That means as soon as code execution leaves the scope (the method), the variable is erased. This also means each time the method is called, a new list is created.

Take this line:

```
List<string> snackList = new List<string>();
```

And move it *outside* your method, and into the scope of the class.